# System of differential equations in Python with the shooting method

Tags: python-3.x, differential-equations

I have some problem with solving deifferential equation in python. Could you please tell me, did i realise correct shooting method and euler method? I have system of nonlinear second order differential equations, with boundary conditions at 0 and at 1.
I used the secant method for finding the values if functions g,f at 1. Output of this program 0,0, It looks like it's not computing anything because the program runs instantly. I've checked, and it enters the loops, but it simply doesn't compute.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Friedbierg-Lee-Sirlin Q-Balls

#Boundary conditions and parameters
k=1
m=0.25
w=0.85

z_one=0
n_one=0
g_zero=1
f_zero=0

#Equations

#r=[0,inf), x=[0,1)
def r(x):
    return -np.log(x)

def dz(z,x,f,g):
    return (1/x**2) * (k*g**2*f - w**2*f - x*z - (2*x/np.log(x)*z))

def dn(n,x,f,g):
    return (1/x**2) * (k*f**2*g - 2*m*g*(1-g**2) - x*n - (2*x/np.log(x)*n))

def dg(n):
    return n

def df(z):
    return z

f=np.zeros(10001)
g=np.zeros(10001)
z=np.zeros(2)
n=np.zeros(2)

#Euler's method
def euler_method(t1,t2):
    x0=1
    h=0.0001
    z[0]=z_one
    n[0]=n_one
    g[0]=t2
    f[0]=t1
    x=x0
    k=0
    while x>(1-9999*0.0001):
        k+=1
        x-=k*h
        z[1]=z[0]-h*dz(z[0],x,f[k-1],g[k-1])
        n[1]=n[0]-h*dn(n[0],x,f[k-1],g[k-1])
        f[k]=f[k-1]-h*df(z[0])
        g[k]=g[k-1]-h*dg(n[0])
        z[0], n[0]= z[1], n[1]    
    return f[9999],g[9999]

#Shooting method
def  shooting_method():
    e=0.00001
    x1=np.zeros(100)
    x2=np.zeros(100)
    x1[0]=0
    x2[0]=1
    y1,y2= euler_method(x1[0],x2[0])
    x1[1]=0.1
    x2[1]=1.05
    y3,y4= euler_method(x1[1],x2[1])
    i=1
    while (abs(y3-f_zero)>e) and (abs(y4-g_zero)>e) and (i<100):
        i+=1
        x1[i]= x1[i-1] - (y3-f_zero)*(x1[i-1]-x1[i-2])/(y3-y1)
        x2[i]= x2[i-1] - (y4-g_zero)*(x2[i-1]-x2[i-2])/(y4-y2)
        y1,y2= euler_method(x1[i-1],x2[i-1])
        y3,y4= euler_method(x1[i],x2[i])
    return y3,y4
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please read [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). "did i realise correct shooting method and euler method" is too broad for us to tackle; we don't write code to specification. [You are expected to study the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) ahead of time; think of logical steps to solve the problem; figure out exactly where you are stuck, and be able to show exact input and output.